# Doesn't appear anything in scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

```
    MainView root = findViewById(R.id.rootPanel);
    TableView tableview = createTableView();
    ScrollView scrollview = new ScrollView(this);
    scrollview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    scrollview.addView(tableview);
    root.addView(scrollview);
```

When i tried to add my custom tablelayout to the scrollview, doesn't appear anything.  But the scrollview recognize the tablelayout (i understood from wrap_content). If i replaced the scrollview with another layout, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I added a intermediate layer between scrollview and table layout and it worked.

ScrollView <- LinearLayout <- TableLayout